# extract text between first and second character

Tags: ms-access-2007

i would like to make a query in ma access can extract text between first and second character "/" and when there are not "/" in field in returns null.

now data in my table are like below

```
No           option1
1            100
2            145/Mechanical/0800
3            120/electrical/1620
4            131/mechanical/0200/dw-001
```

Now I like to make a query can extract text between first and second character "/" like below:

```
 No       option1                   discipline
 1        100                   null
 2        145/Mechanical/0800           Mechanical
 3        120/electrical/1620           electrical
 4        131/mechanical/0200/dw-001        mechanical
```

Comment: i like to use that for example in sql what i have to do? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT [No], option1, 
       IIF(INSTR(option1,'/') > 0, 
           MID(option1, 
               INSTR(option1,'/')+1, 
               INSTR(INSTR(option1,'/')+1,option1,'/')-INSTR(option1,'/')-1
           ),
           NULL
       ) AS discipline
  FROM YourTable
```